# WhatsApp Web Service for OTP Verification Not Delivering Messages

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm trying to implement OTP verification for my website using WhatsApp's web services to send messages. When I use their site panel or POSTMAN requests, there are no errors reported, and it appears as if the messages are sent successfully. However, the messages are not being delivered to me, and the sent messages count remains at zero.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? What could be preventing the messages from being delivered, despite the absence of any error messages during the send process?

I use their site panel or POSTMAN requests, there are no errors reported, and it appears as if the messages are sent successfully. However, the messages are not being delivered to me.